# User location via ip-api only works on local

Tags: javascript, ip

I am very new to web development and I suspect this is a simple issue.

When I run my website via VScode my landing page displays the users region and city name onload. When I upload the same code to my website it returns nothing. I'm having trouble even displaying an error message in order to debug. I tried to get location.origin because this api apparently requires a "non null origin". I don't even fully understand how ACAO works.

```
//Display users location in welcome message via IP
function locate() {
fetch('https://ip-api.com/json/')
.then(function(response) {
  response.json().then(jsonData => {
      data = jsonData;
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = `Come in, ${data.city}, ${data.regionName}. Everyone is welcome.`
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
//Attempt at getting some information on the issue.
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = `Come in, ${location.origin}. Everyone is welcome.`
    console.log(error)
});
};
```

All help, and constructive criticism, is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your website using ssl?(https://) It looks like you can only use it on non ssl (http://) sites unless you upgrade to the paid version. I'm assuming you are using the free version as there doesn't appear to be any api key being used in your example. 

If you check your browsers network tab for the request do you see an error there? I was seeing this error: 

    {"status":"fail","message":"SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/"}

Until I tried running the code on a site that doesn't have ssl.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I changed my api for ip information but the website data was cached in the browser. I had to shift + reload the page to see the updated web page.